# When aquiring a company and website, how should their website be redirected?

Tags: seo, redirects

A few months ago the company that I work for acquired another company along with their website. Recently we took their site down and simply redirected the url of the acquired site via DNS to ours.

Is this the best way to handle the redirects or should we have redirected old pages to the relevant new pages on our website? We adjusted the DNS about a week ago and Google seems to be doing a fairly decent job of figuring out which pages to take the user to. For example when I google one of their products the new page on our site comes up in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DNS is **not** a redirect. You simply pointed another domain name to the same server. Nothing more. There is serious danger in this in that you will/can end up with duplicate content that will harm SERP performance severely.

TO avoid this, traditionally, you would want to have both domains configured on a web server (it does not have to be the same server) and do a 301 redirect from the old site to the new site. Often this is done with a blanket redirect from the old companies site to the new site and then redirects for particular pages one at a time on the new site to match the URI from the old site to point to the appropriate page on the new site. If you do not have a matching page from the old site to the new site, it is okay to let it return a 404 `Not Found` error though if you can, a 410 `Gone` error is better but may be more work that you want to do. This way, you avoid the duplicate content issue.

I would suggest doing this quickly since you have already allowed the search engines spider both sites. You will want to make the changes quickly to avoid as much loss of SERP performance as possible. This can be done with an audit of both sites and not worrying about pages that do not matter. Just focus on the ones that do matter.

[Update]

Here is an example of a blanket redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I would be putting this on the old site to redirect the entire thing over to the new site.

Here is an example of a specific page redirect:

```
Redirect permanent /about/aboutus.html  http://www.newsite.com/aboutus/
```

I would be putting this on the new site to redirect specific pages one at a time. Of course, you can redirect entire directories or do not need a redirect of the URI (path/pages) are identical.

Comment: Doesn't the blanket 301 from the old site remove the page that the user was originally on? So what good is the 301 from the old page to the new page on the new website/server? So if I try to go to www.aquired.com/product/blue-widget and it redirects to www.new-owner.com, what good is the redirect from /product/blue-widget on the server where www.new-owner.com resides?

Comment: My bad!! If you want the old page on the new server, you simply move it over. If the sites use two different CMS, then there is a technical issue that has to be looked at. But it does not sound like this is your situation. Perhaps I am not understanding you correctly. I got that you have both domain names pointing to the same site. Is that right??

Comment: Ok, that's basically what we did, blanket redirect from the old site to the new and recreated the pages on our new site. The urls are not the same thought, should I create redirects that mimic the old site/page structure to the new?

Comment: I would only for the pages on the old site I want represented. I would then find the best page on the new site to redirect to. Otherwise, I would not redirect a page from the old site that I do not care about. That way, it will 404 error and be removed from the search engines eventually.

Comment: So this redirect is basically just created for search engines correct? Since the blanket redirect from the old site goes to the home page of the new.

Comment: When I use the term blanket redirect, I am saying that the entire site is being redirected. Then on the new site, you do the work of redirecting on a page by page basis. I will update the answer.

Comment: So in your example above is /about/aboutus.html a page that was on the old site? If so, then that redirect would be strictly for search engines and not site visitors since that blanket redirect takes any user visiting oldsite.com/about/aboutus.html to www.newsite.com.

Comment: Yes. It is a page on the old site. It wold help the search engine primarily, however, any user that hits the old site with /about/aboutus.html would be redirected to the new site and new page. The blanket redirect simply moves the request for oldsite.com/about/aboutus.html to newsite.com/about/aboutus.html. If this page does not exist, then a redirect on the new site is needed to correct the reference to the right page.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the blanket redirect. Is a blanket redirect possible on a windows server?

Comment: Yes. But I have no idea how that is done exactly. This appears to be the documentation on this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969%28v=ws.10%29.aspx though it is for IIS 7 and not 8. I assume that they are identical or similar. You can get to the IIS 8 documentation from this page. If anyone has an IIS example, they can edit my answer and I will accept it or they can create an answer and I will up-vote it.